# How can I execute a command after searching with `/`?

Tags: autocmd, events

After a search command `/` (*i.e.*, in normal mode) is done, I would like another command to be executed automatically. At the moment the other command should be `:normal! zz`, in order to center the found line.

Previously I had a solution where both the search command (either `/` or `search()`) and the center command `zz` run in the Ex command-line concatenated by `|`.

But this way is now not appropriate.

An autocommand would be suitable, but in the list of available events such an event "do after each search command" is not contained.

I have found this internet article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535350/creating-a-user-defined-event-in-vim

This sounds to be just the solution to my question. But in vim help I read that `User` will never be executed automatically. Thus not suitable.

Is this possible at all?

I am using vim version 8.2, in the moment in KNOPPIX 9.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "classic" solution remaps various search keys:

```
" If you have other <Enter> mappings, you might want `:nmap` here
:cnoremap <expr> <Enter> getcmdtype =~# '[?/]' ? '<CR>zz' : '<CR>'
:nnoremap n nzz
:nnoremap N Nzz
" etc.
```

but I have had problems with this in the past (I can't recall exactly how, but occasionally `zz` would show up in my buffer).

I must not be having the same problems now, because I use the following mappings:

```
nnoremap <silent> n n:call bk#cursor#blink(0.2)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call bk#cursor#blink(0.2)<cr>
```

where the function is defined in my personal autoload like

```
function bk#cursor#blink(time) abort
  call bk#cursor#hl_on()
  let time_in_ms = float2nr(a:time * 1000)
  if has('timers')
    let _ = timer_start(time_in_ms, {_ -> bk#cursor#hl_off()})
  else
    exec 'sleep'  time_in_ms  'm'
    call bk#cursor#hl_off()
  endif
endfunction

function bk#cursor#hl_on() abort
  set cursorline cursorcolumn
  redraw
endfunction

function bk#cursor#hl_off() abort
  set nocursorline nocursorcolumn
  redraw
endfunction
```

Coupled with `:set hlsearch` (optionally https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool) and a mapping on `<space><space><space>` (triple-`<leader>`) that calls the same blink function, I almost never lose my place anymore.

Comment: Should this be a `cnoremap <expr> <Enter>` (instead of `nnoremap`) to trap the Enter at the end of the `/` command-line?

Comment: Hm, probably @filbranden. Changing

Comment: I have `nnoremap n nzzzv` and `nnoremap N Nzzzv` in my vimrc so anything that happens to be in a fold is uncovered.